# Content-based image retrieval

Tags: asp.net, image, search, c#-4.0

I want to store scanned images  into the database. If I get a new image, I want to search the database to to find similar images and show the most similar one.
   Can someone give me a hint where I can find the documentation for the methods necessary for that?
   Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built into the BCL that will do that for you.

Take a look at [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page):

> Emgu CV is a cross platform .Net wrapper to the Intel OpenCV image processing library.